# ASP.NET deployed application stops responding

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, production-environment

We have an ASP.NET deployed application running on IIS 7. Lately we started having problems with the website, which usually starts at high traffic times, and the issue is that the page stops loading without showing an error. It essentially continues spinning and does not load. IIS reset would usually fix the issue but we have tried everything to resolve it with no success. Below are additional information about what we have already tried.I can intentionally put the website into this state by running 25 concurrent users to the landing page after which I would have to reset iis because it would stop responding. I am thinking this might have to do with a settings in IIS. Maximum Concurrent Connection is set to the default which is 4294967295. Kind of at a lost here.

- We turned on Failed log tracing on IIS. The data in the error log did not provide anything conclusive.This might be partly related to the request not failing completely hence no log was created. Most errors were collected based on time the page took to respond.
- I have also looked at the app pool and host log files and found nothing out of place

Answer (score 0):

25 concurrent users is nothing. What's the back end stack? There's not too many details listed here but I'd start with looking at each stage the request is in and in addition enable failed request tracing. Mike (formerly from the IIS team) has a great write up on this, in a nutshell though:

[Troubleshoot hanging requests on IIS in 3 steps](http://mvolo.com/troubleshoot-iis-hanging-requests/)

View requests

```
%windir%system32inetsrvappcmd list requests /elapsed:30000
```

Enabled Failed Request Tracing (modify if not using Default Web Site of course)

```
%windir%system32inetsrvappcmd configure trace "Default Web Site" /enablesite 
%windir%system32inetsrvappcmd configure trace "Default Web Site" /enable /path:test.aspx /timeTaken:00:00:30
```

Then hopefully you can find some details via

```
appcmd list traces | findstr "yourpage.aspx"
```